# AWS Batch job triggering multiple times for same event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-batch

I have an AWS Batch job queue that is targeted by an Eventbridge rule. The rule triggers upon completion of a Sagemaker training job. Here's the rule's event pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail-type": ["SageMaker Training Job State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "TrainingJobStatus": ["Completed"],
    "Tags": {
      "model": ["model_tag"]
    }
  }
}
```

Every time the Sagemaker training job completes, the Eventbridge triggers twice and the Batch job runs twice. Here's a screenshot from the rule's monitoring tab:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I get the Eventbridge rule to trigger only once for each matching event?